# Customizing matlab plots for high resolution and custom scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 1d signal of many samples (millions). I also have it's wavelet transform coefficients (in float64) and frequencies stored in arrays. I am trying to make a high resolution plot of both the signal level vs time and also of the scallogram. The default parameters for size etc are too small for effective visualization. I am exporting it to both png and pdf using savefig object.

I would like to make it higher resolution (1920*1080 or equivalent sizes depending upon aspect ratio). I am unable to comprehend matplotlib arguments and objects and unfortunately I have not been able to follow well with tutorials available online. There is so much functionality and different ways of doing it, that moving from one resource to another for learning required re learning something new for the same task.

So far I have been able to understand interpolation choices, colormap choices, figure label, x and y labels. I am unable to understand the difference between imshow and plot, how to pass on size and fidelity of the plot etc, or passing the axis scales (currently my scales are off). The figsize is mentioned in inches and I am not sure how it relates to pixels. Would love to hear guidance on the same.

I would also like to plot STFT for my samples with high image fidelity with custom window size etc. Currently using specgram but would like to know how to pass on window size, overlap etc and the color map and interpolation schemes, and if other alternatives are available.

I'm plotting these for multiple different data sets in a single code (for loop) and would like to have all images being of uniform size and same scale since all have equal sample sizes.

Comment: In general this is too vague for us to answer.  But fig size in pixels is fig size in inches times dpi.   The figure accepts a dpi argument and typically defaults to 100.  If you want to save a png with 1920 pixels save at 100 dpi and 19 inches, or if the fonts are too small, try to save at 200 dpi and 9.5 inches

Comment: Thank you very much John! I earlier was unable to recognise dpi and the figsize together give pixelcount and hence I got confused. I am new to the language and couldn't figure this out. Now I am getting the image quality and size required.